# How to capture match group

Tags: javascript, regex, match, regex-group

Given string

`"1s func(), 2s func()"`

Wanted result

`['func()', 'func()']`

Tried

`/[A-z]*\(.*\)/g`

Unfortunately only results in 1 match
`['func(), 2s func()']`

Because 
`'), 2s func('` passes `.*`

Comment: I would say `.*?` is the way to go if you didn't have `func()`  as the examples. If it's not a language function, why have _func_, if it is, then this isn't a way to parse a function body `(..)`.

Comment: Yeah, this is for parsing a string parameter into an invokable function through AngularJs's $apply method. The 1s 2s are the delay before the functions kick in. The accepted answer works for me but if you have something better then thanks too :)

Comment: Don't know JS but if you think there will not be anything like `func(var1,")",var3)` then have at it !

Comment: Thanks sln! Just tested your given scenario. Thankfully the regex still works fine. Cheers :)

Comment: Oh, so i guess you're pointing that foreign scripts can be injected? xD

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I will consider your tip :)

Comment: I know it's always good to test, but without testing, I can tell you `[A-Za-z]*\(.*?\)` matches `func(var1,")`",var3)`

Comment: You're right, but i'm working on something that will be used by my team mates, whom I'm sure knows it is wrong to write what you have just given as an example. Sln unless, you can show me the regex to do what you want to be done then I won't really bother that much about it lol

Comment: It's your call dude. Recursion and balanced text matching can be accomplished, but not by using JavaScript, no functionality for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[A-Za-z]*\(.*?\)
            ^^
```

Make it non greedy.

Also change the character selector to `[A-Za-z]`, rather than `[A-z]`, to avoid all the intermediate ASCII characters.